# How do I Register Meteor Spacebars Helpers?

Tags: javascript, meteor, spacebars

Trying to make some simple handlebars helpers

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('if_eq', function(context, options) {
  if (context == options.hash.compare)
    return options.fn(this);
  return options.inverse(this);
});
```

Getting this error.

```
ReferenceError: Handlebars is not defined
```

What's the correct way to do it.

Comment: This also happens when you are writing a package and forget the `api.use('handlebars', 'client')` in `package.js`.

Comment: Same cause, similar error: `Object #<Object> has no method 'registerHelper'`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the Handlebars object is only available on the client. So make sure you have `if (Meteor.isClient) { }` wrapped around the helper registration code

Comment: it doesn't seem to be the case, meteor templates are run on both the client and the server?

Comment: @Harry: templates for now are only run on the client - see [Meteor's roadmap on Trello](https://trello.com/c/Lz07fBAm/7-server-side-rendering).