# What are some use-cases for Meteor.isClient?

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

The docs on docs.meteor.com are very lacking for this check. I've seen [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13062463/meteor-how-to-register-handlebars-helpers/13065441#13065441) that it is useful for setting up helper functions in a Handlebars (and the new Spacebars?) JS. But where else would a Meteor.isClient check be required?

Answer (score 3):

It's useful whenever you have shared code between the client and the server. For example, the default code that comes with any new meteor project puts all of the javascript into a single file. `Template` definitions won't work on the server, so they need to be wrapped within a `Meteor.isClient` check. Of course in a larger project, you can easily separate these sections into their respective `/client` and `/server` directories. However, you could still have utility functions, or methods defined in a shared directory. In those cases you may again find that some portions of the code only make sense when executed in one of the two environments.

#### TL;DR

They are critical for small apps where all of the code exists in a single file. Larger apps tend to use them only for things like meteor methods which can have a single definition but work differently depending on the environment.