# How do I define custom template helpers in Meteor.js to format data being fed in?

Tags: javascript, meteor, spacebars

I've been trying to create a custom handle bar template helper like this:

```
Handlebar.registerHelper('customHelper', function (originalData) {
    // Format the original data
    return formattedData;
});
```

Here is how I would like to use it within my template:

```
<div>
    {{#customHelper}}
        {{originalData}}
    {{/customHelper}}
</div>
```

i.e. there is a raw data being fed in to the template, and as soon as I see this data, I would like to apply some custom formatting to this data. I've being trying solutions from some sources

http://handlebarsjs.com/block_helpers.html

[How do I Register Meteor Spacebars Helpers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13062463/meteor-how-to-register-handlebars-helpers)

But none of them tells me what is the correct way to pass in that data to the custom helper and how to handle it.

The error I see in my implementation when I just try to return a string in the helper:

Expected template or null, found: "string"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the correct way to do it, just change my template to:

```
<div>{{customHelper originalData}}</div>
```

will do the trick.

Comment: Correct. You can also pass static data into the helper `<div>{{customHelper 'bla'}}</div>`